# I want to exclude password field from the response, I am using prisma.js

Tags: typescript, orm, prisma

I am trying to exclude password filed from a query response. I have also tried two solution which is already published (https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5042, https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7380) which is not working. is we need to select all field the that we want

```
  let user: UserWithoutPassword = await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            DOB: moment(dob).toDate()
        },
        select: {
            id: true,
            firstName: true,
            lastName: true,
            email: true,
            DOB: true,
            createdAt: true,
            updatedAt: true
        }
    })
```

is there any other solution for these?.

Answer (score 0):

What you have linked to are not solutions but feature requests that we would need to implement. For now, you just need to use `select` on whichever attributes you require.

Answer (score 0):

delete the fields to be excluded before returning the object.
like in your case:

```
delete user["password"];
return user;
```